# How to configure and tell Auth0 to give back authentication tokens with Authorities (JWT)

Tags: jwt, authorization, auth0

I'm simply trying to get Auth0 to give me `GrantAuthority`s after authentication.

*Note: I am using Java Spring, although not necessarily relevant to my problem.*

I have enable Authentication with Auth0 and have a post-consent handler that does something like this:

```
Tokens tokens = controller.handle(request, response);
TokenAuthentication tokenAuth = new TokenAuthentication(JWT.decode(tokens.getIdToken()));
```

Within this `token` object, I'm able to call methods like `getClaims()` which is Auth0's custom way of storing user information.

However, in Spring, I need to things like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER')")` and the only way I'm aware of doing that is to set `GrantAuthority`s returned in Auth0 `JWT` when the user logs in (post-consent callback). From here, I personally mark the request as authenticated for the user by doing `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuth);`.

The point is that the token comes from Auth0 and is cryptographically signed, so I don't believe there's a way I can modify the token or create a new one in any way that makes sense. If this is wrong, please advise me.

Therefore, the only way I can imagine me being able to assign a user an token/session with required Authorities is for Auth0 to give me a token with GrantAuthorities such that `tokenAuth.getAuthorities()` has the roles that I wish the user to have and I can check for per each future request. Currently, this is empty from Auth0 and has no Authorities.

Furthermore, I was previously under the impression that adding [APIs to Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/01-authorization) (then authorizing the API for an App, creating and using the App's identifier as the `audience`, and then setting a user's permissions as ones for that API) would return *Auth0 permissions* as Authorities, but this is not the case.

- **I'm confused as to what these permissions are for and how they would
  be useful to me if I cannot view them in a token.**
- **I'm confused as to how I would get Auth0 to pass me any sort of Authorities that I can
  use at all.**